# What is the meaning of "Number of Replicas" in the pop-up window when Galaxybase starts the cluster?

Tags: graph-databases

I'm using a graph database called Galaxybase database. What is the meaning of "Number of Replicas" in the pop-up window when Galaxybase starts the cluster?

When the number of replicas shows 1, does it mean that a backup copy will be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galaxybase supports multi-replica mechanism for data. By setting the number of replicas, data can be backed up across nodes.
The default number of replicas is 1, which means no backup is performed. When the number of replicas is set to 2, a backup copy of the data will be generated, and so on.